# Waiting for Vector & WFS loading

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, loading

*user borrowed from friend*

since i use vector layer with wfs protocol, there is a little while before features loaded on the map. So i need to tell user to wait a moment until they load.

what best way to do that ? 
i found this http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Patch-quot-waiting-quot-mouse-cursor-on-WFS-loading-td3961983.html

but not sure if it will work. any body tried it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the LoadingPanel addin: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Addins/LoadingPanel

This could easily be altered to show a "waiting cursor" by altering the "minimizeControl" and "maximizeControl", removing the

```
this.div.style.display = "none";
this.div.style.display = "block";
```

lines and adding:

```
document.body.style.cursor='auto'
document.body.style.cursor='wait'
```

Comment: this is for raster tiles, will it work for vectors?

Comment: yes, it works for vectors also