# LoadingPanel - Waiting for Vector & WFS loading

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, wfs, loading

I have vector layer with WFS protocol. and because I have a huge amount of data, there is a while before features loaded on the map.

So i need to tell user to wait a moment until they load by display a "waiting" animation.

I found this [Waiting for Vector & WFS loading](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26072/waiting-for-vector-wfs-loading)

and tried it with no luck so far.

here is what I did:

- I placed the LoadingPanel.js
- I added this stylesheet:

  ```
  <style type="text/css">

  .olControlLoadingPanel {

          background-image:url(loading.gif);

          position: relative;

          width: 195px;

          height: 11px;

          background-position:center;

          background-repeat:no-repeat;

          display: none;

      }

   </style>`
  ```
- and finally added the LoadingPanel control :

  `map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LoadingPanel());`

Comment: Have a look at this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31206/3895

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be your z-index? This works for me [here](http://geoserver_sandbox.capecodgis.com/)

```
.olControlLoadingPanel {
background-image: url(../OpenLayers/theme/default/img/load.gif);
left:45%;
top: 45%;
position: absolute;
width: 250px;
height:250px;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: none;
z-index: 1000;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but does that work with vactor/wfs layer?

Comment: I think so. I looked at LoadingPanel.js and it seems to be activated by layers, not layer type.